# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 with OS Monterey

Tags: c++, clang++, macos-monterey

I just reinstall my system from OS HighSierra to OS Monterey and restart my system from scratch. I reinstall XCode from AppleStore, but after that when I try to compile C++ and there is class in the code, the compiler doesn't have access to the function of class himself and the console return message like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "random_double(double, double, std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271u, 0u, 2147483647u>&)", referenced from:
      vec2<double>::rand(double const&, double const&, double const&, double const&, std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271u, 0u, 2147483647u>&) in test_random-9ab46f.o
  "random(float, float, std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271u, 0u, 2147483647u>&)", referenced from:
      vec2<float>::rand(float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271u, 0u, 2147483647u>&) in test_random-9ab46f.o
      vec3<float>::rand(float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271u, 0u, 2147483647u>&) in test_random-9ab46f.o
      vec4<float>::rand(float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, float const&, std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271u, 0u, 2147483647u>&) in test_random-9ab46f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

for information, my script is

```
path_test="../test/"
path="../rope/"
path_template="../rope/template/"
path_class="../rope/class/"
path_function="../rope/function/"
clang++ -std=c++11 \
${path_test}main.cpp \
${path}*.cpp ${path}*.hpp \
${path_template}utils/*.hpp \
&& ./a.out 100 10 \
&& rm ${path}*.gch ${path_template}utils/*.gch
```

I'm not sure the C++ code is important but in case the code can be available here : https://github.com/StanLepunK/Rope_cpp/tree/master/rope

Comment: Do you have multiple cpp files? Could also be that you haven't installed the CLT.

Comment: @sweenish the `CLT`is not include with the `Xcode` installation ?

Comment: Do not pass `.hpp` files as arguments to the C++ compiler (unless you want to build precompiled headers, which you apparently don't).

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. I've the same probleme with my `OF` program, before that's work and after not. And in `OF` the build system is solid... not like mine :) So I think `.hpp` is not the problem. https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/how-dealing-with-class-in-of-or-cpp/39146/2

Comment: @sweenish when i pass `xcode-select --version` in the terminal that's return `xcode-select version 2392.`

Comment: That would be the version of the xcode-select tool. Not the CLT.

Comment: @sweenish hmmm, when i pass `xcode-select --install` the console return `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates` I presume `CLT`is installed...

Comment: They are. You might just need to reboot. I remember going through all this a while ago. I had just lost access. Everything had to be updated and ran and checked, but eventually I still had to reboot as well.

Comment: @sweenish I just restart my computer and relaunch `VScode ` same result. :(

Comment: `random_double`  should be defined in `rope/function/rand.cpp`, did you link that into your compile command (direcly, via static lib or dynamic lib) ?

Comment: Any reason to use VScode over Xcode?

Comment: You are not compiling all the files you need. You need .cpp files from rope/function. I recommend writing a makefile or using another proper build system. A shell script is not a viable build system.

Comment: thx @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. you right there miss *.cpp` in my script, now I must resolve my `OF` problem https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/how-dealing-with-class-in-of-or-cpp/39146/4